# R: Identifying the first and last elements in a repeating set of duplicates

Tags: r, repeat

```
  Img  Time
1  B    1
2  B    2
3  B    3
4  B    7
5  B    8
6  B    11
7  G    12
8  G    14
9  G    16
10 G    21
```

Hi all,

Above is an overly simplified version of the type of data I am working with. I have images (*Img*) presented for a certain duration of time (*Time*).


I want to know how long each Img was presented for, however, the data I have makes it difficult to get that information. There is no unique value to indicate when a image started or stopped, and the timer doesn't reset after a new image is shown. 


I want to create a new column that shows how much time passes with respect to when the image was first shown. Example below:

```
  Img  Time  ElapTime
1  B    1       1
2  B    2       2
3  B    3       3
4  B    7       7
5  B    8       8
6  B    11      11
7  G    12      1
8  G    14      3
9  G    16      5
10 G    21      10
```

Is there a way to identify the first and last elements within a repeating sequence? Knowing that might help me create an adjusted time column. 


 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'Img' and subtract the 'Time' from the `first` 'Time'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Img) %>%
   mutate(ElapTime = Time - first(Time) + 1)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   Img [2]
#     Img  Time ElapTime
#   <chr> <int>    <dbl>
# 1     B     1        1
# 2     B     2        2
# 3     B     3        3
# 4     B     7        7
# 5     B     8        8
# 6     B    11       11
# 7     G    12        1
# 8     G    14        3
# 9     G    16        5
#10     G    21       10
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$ElapTime <-  with(df1, ave(Time, Img, FUN = function(x) x- x[1]+1))
```

Comment: dplyr seems to be the solution to all my problems, lol. Thank you so much, this works perfectly!